# Problem in sending JSON data to the yahoo server with POST message

Tags: javascript, json, yui

I am trying this code in Javascript. But its not working.... 
The postData is json data sent to the server to be saved.
I have checked that JSON data needs to be parsed or stringify... is that the problem..
or I am doing some other silly mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have handleSuccess defined twice.  The second time is a no-op.  Get rid of the second 'var handleSuccess = ...' and put in a handleFailure definition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you have even not JSON string. It is just invalid string.
You need to put it in ''.

```
var postData ='_out=json&name=justtryit&def={"layout":[{"id":"sw-156","xy":[168,80]},{"id":"_OUTPUT","xy":[508.33331298828125,95.81666564941406]}],"modules":[{"type":"fetch","id":"sw-156","conf":{"URL":{"value":"www.sports.yahoo.com","type":"url"}}},{"type":"output","id":"_OUTPUT","conf":{}}],"terminaldata":[],"wires":[{"id":"_w1","src":{"id":"_OUTPUT","moduleid":"sw-156"},"tgt":{"id":"_INPUT","moduleid":"_OUTPUT"}}]}&rnd=7821&.crumb=P.r4cQGAC.Y';
```

It should work if you are doing right call

Comment: Thanks for a answer... I just tried a above change putting single quotes instead of double quote..any oar problem you think can be?

Comment: Thanks for a answer Eldar... I tried a single quotes but it didn't worked....can you are be some oar problem ....

Comment: Check if there any call browser sends. Use firebug plugin for this in Firefox. Net tab.